# Best practices for file storage across multiple services?

Tags: c#

I came to coclusion what in my system I often want to manipulate not over actual files, but over references and in some cases metha-information about files (size, different types of hashes, extensions, defferent tags, etc), but where to store it all? I mean, I can easily create service with contract above almost anything: be it MS SQL or even simple shared folder.

But what is best practices? Main benefactor I look for is - speed. File retrieval should be as fast as possible, whether it's 4gb or 200mb, and I don't realy know how fast will be shared folder above MS SQL.

So, I appreciate if you tell, how you solve this problem (which system do you use, frameworks) and what is advantages/disadvantages of your selected choise?

**PS:** I know it's too broad, but well, we are not machines so sometimes question don't have real, single, answer but just food for thoughts.

Comment: If you looked for the speed, then "cashing" is one way - you can save all data you need about file(in database for example) every time you change/create file. Then accessing those information don't need to reading file itself

Comment: Well, im not asking about speed of metha retrieval, Im asking about where to store/index if needed thousands of 1gb file.

Comment: If you aware about speed, then you should specify how you will use those files/data. Optimization solution always depends on the specific scenario of using data. Without this kind of information your question is broad and asking for frameworks.

Comment: The main reason behind file service - is to serve files. Thats the use case.

Comment: _serve files_ is broad definition of service. You can only save once and read multiple times, you can update files, should you proved access to files for writing for multiple users simultaneously - there are a lot of scenarios and every scenario will need different solutions

Comment: nope, one write/delete/multiple reads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single best practice to solve your problem, it basically depends on your exact use-case.

While deciding where and how to store your files you should address and consider few things and possibilities:

1. Local File System

   1.1. Do your files need to be accessible from *N* server instances, i.e. you have distributed system? *If that's the case, Local File System storage is not an option.*

   1.2. Does the Read/Write speed of your hard drive suits your performance needs? *You should think about drives which are best suited for file storage.*
2. Database

   2.1. What's the average size of files you working on? *There are different options to store files inside MS SQL database.*

   2.2. How strong is your database server? *If you are having distributed environment, you should keep in mind that database load will be higher due to additional file storage management and handling.*

   2.3. There are plenty of research papers and posts related to this topic, here are few of them:

   - [To BLOB or Not To BLOB](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2006/04/tr-2006-45.pdf)
   - [Storing BLOBs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/compare-options-for-storing-blobs-sql-server)
3. Cloud Storage (Amazon s3, Azure File storage, etc...)

   3.1. How good is server's network bandwidth? *You should be aware that the server will fetch file via network*

   3.2. Do you find the storage expenses suitable? *There are different options, you should research what's the best for your use-case*

Since your question is too broad, I just dropped few things to think about. Hopefully, this will give you slightly broader view of your particular problem.

Last but not least, meta data and storage *reference* should be stored inside database. You can even achieve (with good table architecture) possibility to have different files stored on a different locations (i.e. multiple servers) in a different way (e.g. LFS, Cloud)

Comment: Well, Indeed good questions, I will think about usage but probably will stop at some database. I just thought there was some install/use system for this purpose, which can transfer file in different ways.